Why do BJT datasheets give a DC version and a small signal version of hFE?
In this datasheet, they give \$h_{FE}\$ and \$h_{fe}\$ as shown in the pictures below. When should I worry about the difference between \$h_{FE}\$ and \$h_{fe}\$?



You should worry because your circuit handles different frequencies differently.

Usually, uppercase subscripts mean absolute figures, and lowercase subscripts mean differential (aka incremental or slope) figures. This data table is no exception. However, there are also different measurement conditions listed in the data sheet, which is perhaps why the two figures seem quite dissimilar, even at the same IC.
hFE has been measured for 1 V VCE, very close to saturated. You will be interested in this value if you want to work out how much current you need to supply the base to get the transistor saturated. hFE does drop as the transistor approaches saturation, and stops working well.
hfe has been measured at 10 V VCE, where you might have it biassed as an amplifier. This will give you the current gain when used as an amplifier.
Arguably, you're more interested in the gm than the hfe once you have the transistor biassed up as an amplifier.

Usually \$h_{FE}\$ is the DC current gain and, \$h_{fe}\$ is the AC current gain. However, sometimes the "h" is capitalized and the subscript letters are non-capitalized but, they still refer to DC and AC current gain respectively. The "f" is for forward transfer and the "e" means common-emitter configuration.
People aren't very careful about how they write this so it must seem confusing to you. Referring to Wiki h-parameter model, etymology...

It appears (clear to me) that the leading "h" should always be lower case.

The small-signal hfe is appropriate when designing small-signal amplifiers. The large-signal gain reported is almost the same at the specified values of IC and this tells us that high injection does not set in at these values of IC. Useful to know this for switching applications.
Note that the range of both current gains is considerable so for design purposes what we get from the data sheet is mostly a minimum value for the current gain. As circuits are usually designed to be tolerate of variations in the current gain a current gain too high is rarely a problem.
